# MySql - Exclude default date from max inside case

Tags: mysql, sql, date, max, case

I am working with a table of items with expiration dates,these items are assigned to users.

I want to get for each user,the highest expiration date.The **issue** here is that default items are initialized with a '3000/01/01' expiration date that should be ignored if another item exists for that user.

I've got a query doing that:

```
SELECT 
    user_id as UserId, 
    CASE WHEN (YEAR(MAX(date_expiration)) = 3000)
        THEN (
            SELECT MAX(temp.date_expiration)
            FROM user_items temp 
            WHERE YEAR(temp.date_expiration) <> 3000 and temp.user_id = UserId
        )
        ELSE MAX(date_expiration) 
    END as date_expiration 
FROM user_items GROUP BY user_id
```

This **works**, but the query inside THEN block is killing performance a bit and it is a huge table.

So,Is there a better way to ignore the default date from the MAX operation when entering the CASE condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  user_id,
        COALESCE(
                MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(date_expiration) = 3000 THEN NULL ELSE date_expiration END),
                MAX(date_expiration)
        )
FROM    user_items
GROUP BY
        user_id
```

If there are few users but lots of entries per user in your table, you can try improving your query yet a little more:

```
SELECT  user_id,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  date_expiration
        FROM    user_items uii
        WHERE   uii.user_id = uid.user_id
                AND date_expiration < '3000-01-01'
        ORDER BY
                user_id DESC, date_expiration DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ),
        (
        SELECT  date_expiration
        FROM    user_items uii
        WHERE   uii.user_id = uid.user_id
        ORDER BY
                user_id DESC, date_expiration DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
        )
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                user_id
        FROM    user_items
        ) uid
```

You need an index on `(user_id, date_expiration)` for this to work fast.